# How should we approach publishing our game from India?

Tags: monetization, publishing

Me and my friends are developing a game using Java for Windows operating system. We have nearly completed our game. As we feel that the game can make money, we wish to sell it. But in India we don't know any game publishing company. 
We want to know the following if possible.
Will game publishers like BigFishGames.com publish our game even though we are not in USA?
We are just students in college. Is it required that we can sell only after we start a company?
Is it possible to sign contracts if the publisher wishes to publish our game, while the publisher and developer are in different countries?
Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, its very hard for a beginner to find a publisher unless you have something, that really stands out of the crowd or something really convincing. So, your first choice should be online distributor. Most famous is [Steam](http://www.store.steampowered.com) which of course has a higher entry margin. There are less restrictive distributors like [Desura](http://www.desura.com).

There is a new Indie only online game distributor emerging, called [IndieCity](http://www.indiecity.com). It hasn't been launched yet, but you can register as a developer and can have access to their api, sumbit game, go through the review system and so forth. It new so it will be relatively easy to have a place for a head start. There are other online distributors too. Google for more info.

You can also hook up your game profile in [Indiedb](http://www.indiedb.com/). Its one of the largest Indie gaming portal.

About BigFish you should check out their FAQ.

Update :
check these too, [10 alternatives of Steam](http://joinpgn.com/contents/articles/08042011550-10-alternatives-to-valves-steam)